# Pinch-Zoom on Asus UX302LG touchscreen

Tags: asus, multi-touch, touchscreen

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

The system only recognizes multitouch tapping like 3 fingers for ***move window***, 4 fingers for ***open dash***, but no mutitouch-gesture that involves holding the fingers on the screen.

Is there a way to activate multitouch gestures like pinch-zoom  or rotate on the touchscreen of an ASUS-Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

I found this : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch
Problem is that the swipe and pinch stuff is only about the trackpad.
Mine does not support it yet, the driver seems not ok.
That link shows what gestures work and hints to some further options.